# File Upload Plugin located in webroot ignores dynamic changes to the destination folder

Tags: php, session, cakephp, uploadify

**What I have:**

I am using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) to upload files for the intranet application that Im writing.

I need to upload files to the directory that belongs to one user (with dynamic creation of directories).

**My obviously incorrect solution :)**

After any user logs in I create him a folder(title is user_id).

**Now uploadify.php looks like this:**

```
    session_name("test_tool_cookie");
    session_start();
    $targetFolder = '/test_tool/app/webroot/uploadify/' . $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id']; //Relative to the root
    //the 3 lines above are my only change to the script
//$targetFolder = '/test_tool/app/webroot/uploadify/tmpFile'; //this was here before my changes

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('html' , 'docx', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'txt'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo '1';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
    }
```

**THE PROBLEM**

- The above script won't upload the file into the folder (checked and
  wont upload the file anywhere else either).
- If I change the $targetFile to a static value, it works fine.
- The Session value is correct (but ignored)

**What else might earn an answered question**

I will mark your question as an answer if you suggest a good multiupload plugin (with a brief description) that is easy to integrate with cake php, and will be customizable, so every object in the database can have it's own folder.

Please think about your answer, any solution for this problem will help a lot.

Comment: Does `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id']` hold a string value if your user is logge in? Does `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder` exist and is writable? If you create the folder, is the parent folder writable for your web user?

Comment: checked it with the is_writable method, returned 1. Checked the Session, it holds a number (php is type insensitive, right)?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: checked the SESSION with is_string and also returned 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you to try send the session name with your form data like on the example [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns.

Because if it returns, lets say `/home/your_username/public_html/test_tool/app/webroot`, which I believe is what happens, and you are adding `/test_tool/app/webroot/uploadify/`, you will never get the file to upload.

From my perspective, you should do the following and leave everything else as is:

```
// As long as $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id'] has a value, it should work. If not, statically place a number there like /uploadify/1 to see if it works
$targetFolder = '/uploadify/' . $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id']; //Relative to the root
```

Comment: When I try it statically, it works fine, so I guess the problem will be with session reading (which in another .php file in this folder returns a correct value).

I did not try lp1051's link advice in Wednesday, today it's not really working, will edit my question soon enough.