# CakePHP How to call a controller function from an external function

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I'm having trouble with [accessing the session in an external .php script located in webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725481/cakephp-accessing-the-session-in-a-php-file-located-in-the-webroot).

Thought I'd write a function getSession() in one of my controllers and try to call it in the .php file.

**So in steps:**

1. I have file.php
2. In a controller I have a function getSession().
3. How to call the controllers function in the file.php?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Meanwhile I fixed my bug, but still am curious how this is done and want other stack users to find a good answer to this so:

Its exactly like this:

In UsersController I have a function:

```
public function getSession() {
    return $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id'];
}
```

That I want to let's say print (for example) like this: print_r(Users.getSession) in the file test.php located in webroot/uploadify/test.php.

This file is not a class, but if it is required, then it shall be :)

@CaboOne: Maybe your answer was correct, I just wasnt sure what code to call (and enter) where :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed I have the following php file in webroot folder:

```
<?php

class TestingClass {

    function getName(){
        return "Test";
    }
}

?>
```

I would do the following:

```
// This would bring you to your /webroot folder
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/another_file.php'; 

// Initializing the class
$example = new TestingClass; 

// Call a function from the initialized class
$a_value = $example->getName(); 


// If you want to use $a_value in the view, you can then set
$this->set('a_value', $a_value);
```

Comment: Hey, CaboONE.

I dont absolutely understand where the second example code should sit.. in webroot, or in the controller?

But thanks, looks realy well, I think this little clarification will be enough for me.

Comment: From your question you said that you wrote a `function getSession()` in one of your controllers to deal with this External File. Didnt you? If you want to post exactly what you did I will change it for you to make it work. Thanks

Comment: Check the EDIT part pls, I will be glad for your answer :)

Comment: Igor, if all you want it the Session, could you just read it on the file you need by calling `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['user_id'];`? At first I thought you were pulling something from root into the CakePHP controller. Now it looks like you are pulling the `_SESSION` info from CakePHP. If you dont want to take this approach, I can provide you with a better answer for you.

Comment: I've already figured that part out, now it was more about me being curious how I'd call a controller function from "outside" cakePHP.

So the getSession is just an example for simplicity.

I really would like an answer.

Comment: why don't anyone post the final code on how to call a cakephp controller function from "outside" cakePHP ? i still can not figure out how to do this simple task.